# Retrieving HTTP.sys logs

Tags: c#, http

I have an application that uses the HttpListener class. In case of errors this produces traces in the HTTPERR directory under LogFiles.

Is there any way to produce similar logs but for all requests against the machine, not just failed ones? I would like to avoid having to do this at the code level if possible.

Answer (score 0):

No. Refer https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784703%28v=ws.10%29.aspx for possible error logging settings.